# Run sub for every dynamically added gridview's databound event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have inherited an old Webforms project where the previous coder dynamically added up to 20 gridviews to a page. I am trying to figure out a way to add a gridview.Databound event handler for each of the grids that is added to the page without writing the same code for twenty different possibilities?

Or some way to bind the event to every possible gridview?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) helps

Comment: any sample code on where the grids are added?  If nothing else create a method that takes a GridView parameter which adds the event to it, and pass in whichever GridView is created when it is created.